Matlab: Problem with logical indexing (combining two vectors with different sample rate)
I have in Matlab two time signals y1(t1) and y2(t2), see 1st diagram. The sample rate of t1 and t2 is different (t2 has a lower sample rate).
Goal: I want to mask y1 based on the value of y2: When y2 is zero then y1 should be zero.
Problem: Because of the different sample rates, I have trouble achieving this --> do you have an idea?
The 2nd diagram shows the desired output for y3 (= masked y1) (green).
t1 = 0:0.01:10;
y1 = sin(t1*10);
% plot(t1, y1)

t2 = 0:1:10;
y2 = t2.*[0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0];
% stairs(t2, y2)

plot(t1, y1)
hold on
stairs(t2, y2)
hold off

% I need a y3 with time t1.
% y3 is zero when y2 is zero.
% y3 = ???

Current output for y1(t1) [blue] and y2(t2) [orange]:

Desired output for y3(t1) [green]:


Final Code After Using the Proposed Solution by User Wolfie
t1 = 0:0.01:10;
y1 = sin( t1 * 10 );
plot( t1, y1 )

t2 = 0:1:10;
y2 = t2 .* [ 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ];
stairs( t2, y2 )

y2_us = interp1( t2, y2, t1,'previous' );
t2_us = interp1( t2, t2, t1 );
stairs( t2, y2 )
hold on
stairs( t2_us, y2_us )
hold off

plot( t1, y1 )
hold on
stairs( t2, y2 )
hold off

y3 = y1 .* ( y2_us > 0 );
plot( t1, y1 )
hold on
stairs( t2, y2 )
plot( t1, y3, 'LineWidth', 4, 'Color', [0, 0.39, 0] )
hold off



You should resample the one signal to match the sampling rate of the other. Try interp1. There are other questions on here that show how to do so.

You can upsample y2 to share a timebase with y1:
% upsample y2 to share timebase t1. 'previous' interp used to mimic
% 'stairs' behaviour, i.e. hold previous value
y2_us = interp1(t2,y2,t1,'previous');

Then create the new array y3 based on y1 and y2:
% Create y3 with timebase t1: =y1 if y2>0, =0 otherwise
y3 = y1 .* (y2_us>0);

Plot to confirm:
plot(t1, y1)
hold on
stairs(t2, y2)
plot(t1, y3)
hold off



I love to learn new things. I've used interp1 almost daily for 15 years and yet I never noticed the 'previous' option and behavior. Nice!

Sorry for my late response: Thanks a lot and +1.
